Custom ObjectMapper @Bean and @Primary is somehow overridden to default ObjectMapper
Custom ObjectMapper @Bean and @Primary is somehow overridden to default ObjectMapper
 @Bean 
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNWRAPPED_TYPE_IDENTIFIERS, false);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID, true);
        mapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"));
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false);
        mapper.registerModule(new WithSchemaTypeModule());
        return mapper;
    }

Still getting failed on unknown properties issues and the date field is number instead of the setformat , this is happens on REST API exposed in jaxrs-jersey .Also the Provider is registered in jaxrs with the ObjectMapper on startup. But in runtime the ObjectMapper seems to be somewhat different irrespective what is configured?
